# Remove Duplicate Values Combo box

Tags: php, combobox

I want to show value into combo box based on two queries.

So this is the example :

Query 1 :

- 401

Query 2 :

- 101
- 201
- 301
- 401
- 501

I want the result inside combo box is :

- 401 (default)
- 101
- 201
- 301
- 501

But my result now is :

- 401
- 101
- 201
- 301
- 401
- 501

This is my code :

```
$query4 = "select ruang from schedule where nim = '".$nim."'";
$query_exec4 = mysqli_query($conn, $query4) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if($data4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_exec4))
{
     $ruang = $data4['ruang']; <----- This is for comparison ---->
     echo "<option value='$ruang'>".$ruang."</option>";
     $query5 = "select ruang from kelas order by ruang ASC";
     $query_exec5 = mysqli_query($conn, $query5) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
     while($data5 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_exec5))
     {
        echo "<option value='$data5['ruang'].'>'".$data5['ruang']."'</option>";
     }
}
```

Could you help me to fix this ?

Comment: So what do you want? Remove duplicates? What is first query?

Comment: Where is the other query?

Comment: Please look at my edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to show result of query1 again use following query:

```
SELECT ruang 
FROM   kelas 
WHERE  ruang NOT IN(SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                    FROM   another_table) 
ORDER  BY ruang ASC
```

Here is above example i am not selecting record which are already present in first table. Subquery i have assumed.

---

Change your second query with this

```
$query5 = "SELECT ruang 
FROM   kelas 
WHERE  ruang NOT IN(SELECT ruang 
                    FROM   schedule where nim = '".$nim."')
ORDER  BY ruang ASC";
```

---

Complete code can be like this:

```
$query4 = "select ruang from schedule where nim = '".$nim."'";
$query_exec4 = mysqli_query($conn, $query4) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($data4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_exec4))
{
     echo "<option value='$ruang'>".$ruang."</option>";
}
$query5 = "SELECT ruang 
FROM   kelas 
WHERE  ruang NOT IN(SELECT ruang 
                    FROM   schedule where nim = '".$nim."')
ORDER  BY ruang ASC";
$query_exec5 = mysqli_query($conn, $query5) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($data5 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_exec5))
{
    echo "<option value='$data5['ruang'].'>'".$data5['ruang']."'</option>";
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.